# Adding database schema to MySQL Workbench

Tags: database-schema, mysql-workbench

I'm using MySQL Workbench 6.0 to create a database based on a previous schema. I have these files:

```
dvds.frm
db.opt
electronics.frm
musics.frm
login_details.frm
```

But I haven't been able to create my database, nor even import these files into MySQL Workbench 6.0.

What should I do?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never import raw MySQL database files. Don't touch them unless you do any form of recovery after a previous accident. Instead you use a MySQL server that has your schema (regardless of their representation on disk). By

> using MySQL Workbench 6.0 to create a database based on a previous schema

do you mean you want to create a model? If so this is done by reverse engineering from a MySQL server or an SQL file. See menu `Database -> Reverse Engineer...`.